# Django not finding Javascript File on Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I´m trying to add Jquery mosaic plugin to my website. However for some reason I can´t get to load the js files that are needed for the plugin

Here´s my file tree and django settins file

[image]

Here´s my template:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/guatepediaapp/jquery.mosaicflow.min.js"></script>
<h1>Prueba Mosaico</h1>

<div class="clearfix mosaicflow">
    <div class="mosaicflow__item">
        <img width="500" height="300" src= "/media/{{ results.1.object.imagen }}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="mosaicflow__item">
        <img width="500" height="500" src="/media/{{ results.2.object.imagen }}" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally my error message:

[image]

Can anyone tell what I´m doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace static with {{ STATIC_URL }}

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}guatepediaapp/jquery.mosaicflow.min.js"></script>
```